# Medical test and travel insurance for UK visas

Tags: insurance, standard-visitor-visas, pakistani-citizens, saudi-airlines

I'm a Pakistani expat. Do I need a medical test and travel insurance for a UK standard visitor visa If I apply from Saudi Arabia?

Comment: You should buy insurance for the risk of medical emergency or accident requiring treatment. The UK national health service would charge you because you are not a resident in the UK, and unpaid medical bills are notified to UK Visas and Immigration

Comment: Please split this question into two - one about the medical test and one about the insurance. Thank you.